# What is the difference between a signal peptide and a transit peptide?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, cell-membrane

From what I know, the two names are used interchangeably and I haven't found any resource which says otherwise either. Is there at all any difference, is there a transit peptide that is not a signal peptide or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Signal peptides** are typically located at the N terminus of a protein. The signal peptides are processed by the translocon machinery and are cleaved off after sorting through the membranes of organelles in the secretory system:

> - endoplasmic reticulum
> - Golgi apparatus
> - ER-Golgi transition vesicles
> - plasma membrane
> - lysosomes

**Transit peptides** target the protein to other subcellular organelles such as ([from UniProt](https://www.uniprot.org/help/transit)):

> - Mitochondrion
> - Apicoplast
> - Chromoplast
> - Chloroplast
> - Cyanelle
> - Thylakoid
> - Amyloplast
> - Peroxisome
> - Glyoxysome
> - Hydrogenosome

N-terminal transit peptides are quite rare. C-terminal transit peptide motifs are much more common. [UniProt holds transit peptides](https://www.uniprot.org/help/transit) as a discrete controlled vocabulary, separate from signal peptides.